# TestFlight TFLog not uploading when there is a crash

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, testflight

When TestFlight crashes I have a log I wish to upload with its crash report.

Following the instructions on their website I came up with this solution, but it doesn't seem to be sending the log I pass to TFLog. However it reports the crash just fine.

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    /*Setup crash handlers for TestFlight so we can send logs. */
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&testFlightHandleExceptions);
    // create the signal action structure
    struct sigaction newSignalAction;
    // initialize the signal action structure
    memset(&newSignalAction, 0, sizeof(newSignalAction));
    // set SignalHandler as the handler in the signal action structure
    newSignalAction.sa_handler = &testFlightSignalHandler;
    // set SignalHandler as the handlers for SIGABRT, SIGILL and SIGBUS
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &newSignalAction, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGILL, &newSignalAction, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGBUS, &newSignalAction, NULL);
    [TestFlight takeOff:TESTFLIGHT_API_KEY];
}

void testFlightHandleExceptions(NSException *exception) {
    [LogManager e: @"Sending crash to TestFlight" Tag:@"AppDelegate"];
    TFLog(@"%@",[LogManager getLog]);
}
```

Where have I gone wrong? Or is there a better way in doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems I can see with this:

1. `testFlightHandleExceptions` is going to be called **after** the crash and it's logs are recorded. Instead you need to be calling `TFLog` inside of `LogManager` every time you log something (before the crash). That's how it's meant to be used.
2. It is **not** ok to use `objc` inside of a signal handler. For that matter, most `c` isn't even allowed.

Hope that helps :)

Jason

Comment: Ah bugger. I don't want to use TFLog all the time as I want control what gets printed on the console. Is there another way to upload the logs with the crash? Hockey has a "crashReportDescription" delegate, does TestFlight have something similar?

Comment: You can turn off TFLog's printing to the console. Would that help?

Comment: Yeah that's what I did thanks :) Maybe an area for TestFlight to improve on in the future.

Comment: Curious. What would you want to change? You don't want to call `TFLog` when logging but would rather give your entire log to TestFlight at crash time?

Comment: Well to make it less confusing is something that could be improved on. 
Hockey has nice delegates when it crashes which allows you to send data up. It doesn't annoy you to use its own logging manager :)
Or maybe just add a notes to your guides for this kind of example. I'll leave it up you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will update the readme :) One of the main reasons we do that is that we upload crashes at crash time, when it's too late to do much. HockeyApp waits until the next time the app opens to get the logs and upload the crash.

Comment: Ah right. Thanks for clearing that up. Just so you know CricHQ(.com) uses TestFlight for our beta testing and its good. It seems we are waiting for the Android sdk too.

Comment: I've some misunderstanding on sending crashes. How can I send crashes or how can i use 'LogManager'? I have not LogManager file. Please help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KhwarezmShah the LogManager stuff is specific to Zammbi's code. You shouldn't have to do anything for crashes to work except set up TestFlight correctly. As for logging, just use TFLog to log things to TestFlight. See the readme here: https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc/1.3.0-beta.4/. If you need more help please contact support: http://help.testflightapp.com

Comment: Thank you @jasongregori. I've fixed. I realized.